# Relaxation of constraints in optimization task with pyomo to speed up computation

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I have a problem with a speed of solving optimization task. My task is to allocate as much wagons as possible from the station of departure to the station of destination and for the minimum cost (two objectives actually). Below is the small example of the problem but in reality I have a lot more variables and it keeps solving for a very long time and still could not find an optimal solution. This problem starts due to the constraint where it requires to keep the balance at each station of arrival at 1/3 for each wagon type (CONSTRAINT 3 in my code). For this small example it works fast but for my real problem it takes an infinity to find the solution. It is very complicated constraint for the model and that's why it causes such an exhaustive computations. Whithout that constarints it works pretty fast even for a lot of variables.
[image]

I have an example of my model on the small dataset for an understanding what's going on. My question is actually is how to speed up the calculations by means of constarint relaxation. I want to add a kind of penalty to the objective function if the constraint of 1/3 is not taken into account for some stations (it is exceeded/underestimated). As I never came across with adding penalties or constarint relaxations maybe someone know how is it possible to apply it to my case. I know there is some techniques as big M, but it is not clear how to apply this in my case. Or maybe there is an another way to do that.

```
import pandas as pd  # 
from pyomo.environ import *

data = {'rem_type' : ['Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type1', 'Type2', 'Type2'],
        'station_depart': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
        'station_arrive': ['B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C'],
        'cost': [100, 103, 111, 101, 105, 114, 95, 99]}
df_route = pd.DataFrame(data)

costs = df_route.set_index(['station_depart', 'station_arrive', 'rem_type']).to_dict()['cost']

# unload
df_unload = pd.DataFrame({'rem_type' : ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type2'], 
                          'station_depart' : ['A', 'A', 'F', 'F'],
                          'volume' : [5, 6, 4, 7]})


demands = df_unload.set_index(['station_depart', 'rem_type']).to_dict()['volume']

# repair
# df_vrp = pd.DataFrame({'rem_type' : ['Type1', 'Type2'], 
#                        'station_arrive' : ['B', 'C'],
#                        'capacity' : [15, 30]})

df_vrp = pd.DataFrame({'rem_type' : ['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type1', 'Type2'], 
                       'station_arrive' : ['B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                       'capacity' : [15, 15, 15, 15]})

capacity = df_vrp.set_index(['station_arrive', 'rem_type']).to_dict()['capacity']

# find the set of available routes and others conveniences
routes = {(s, t) for (s, t, costs) in costs.keys()}
start_nodes = {k[0] for k in costs.keys()}
end_nodes = {k[1] for k in costs.keys()}
all_nodes = start_nodes | end_nodes

# Target Ratios   
ratios =    {('Type1', 'Type2') : (3, 1)
            }

# MODEL

# create model
model = ConcreteModel("OP")

# SETS
model.N = Set(initialize=sorted(all_nodes))
model.S = Set(within=model.N, initialize=sorted(start_nodes))       # the set of start nodes
model.T = Set(within=model.N, initialize=sorted(end_nodes))         # the set of terminations
model.R = Set(within=model.N * model.N, initialize=sorted(routes))  # the set of connections
model.V = Set(initialize=['Type1', 'Type2'])                        # vehicle types
model.ratio_pairs = Set(within=model.V * model.V, initialize=ratios.keys())

# PARAMS
model.cost         = Param(model.R, model.V, initialize=costs)
model.demand       = Param(model.S, model.V, initialize=demands, default=0)  # the demand to send from s of type v
model.capacity     = Param(model.T, model.V, initialize=capacity, default=0) # the capacity to accept at t type v
model.ratio_limits = Param(model.ratio_pairs, initialize=ratios, domain=Any)

# VARS
model.send = Var(model.R, model.V, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)  # send this number of vehicles of type v on route r

# OBJ1: Route as much as possible
model.obj1 = Objective(expr=sum_product(model.send), sense=maximize)

# CONSTRAINT 1
@model.Constraint(model.S, model.V)
def demand_limit(model, s, v):
    return sum(model.send[r, v] for r in model.R if r[0] == s) <= model.demand[s, v]

# CONSTRAINT 2
@model.Constraint(model.T, model.V)
def capacity_limit(model, t, v):
    return sum(model.send[r, v] for r in model.R if r[1] == t) <= model.capacity[t, v]

# CONSTRAINT 3 (the ratio constraint of 1/3 at each station of arrival)
@model.Constraint(model.T, model.ratio_pairs)
def ratio_limit(model, t, v1, v2):
    return sum(model.send[r, v1] for r in model.R if r[1] == f"{t}") * model.ratio_limits[v1, v2][0] == \
           sum(model.send[r, v2] for r in model.R if r[1] == f"{t}") * model.ratio_limits[v1, v2][1]

# solve first pass
results = SolverFactory("glpk").solve(model)
results.write()

# now, add a constraint to make sure we deliver at least as much as before and introduce a
# new cost objective

model.min_send = Constraint(expr=sum_product(model.send) >= value(model.obj1))

model.obj2 = Objective(expr=sum_product(model.cost, model.send), sense=minimize)

model.obj1.deactivate()

results = SolverFactory("glpk").solve(model)

results.write()
model.send.display()
```

Comment: Before even thinking about such hacks, I would try a better MIP solver.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use commercial solvers such as gurobi, for example. I think for MIP problems there are not many alternatives to glpk except commercial solver as gurobi.

Comment: There are a few. Eg CBC, SCIP, HiGHS.

Comment: Thank you. I tried CBC and ithis solver speeded up my calcs significantly.